# Bag Of Words For Text C#

Tags: c#, cpu-word, bag

Is there any tool for creating a Bag of Words model and computing features vector for strings in C#?
Something like pythons CountVectorizer:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",   
                         tokenizer = None,    
                         preprocessor = None, 
                         stop_words = None,   
                         max_features = 1000)
```